# Python: trying to fix indentation error

Tags: python

```
class Cylinder(object):
    self.pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self,height=1,radius=1):
        self.height = height
        self.radius = radius

    def volume(self):
        return self.pi * self.radius**2 * self.height

    def surface_area(self):
        pass
```

Comment: class Cylinder(object):
        self.pi = 3.14
    def __init__(self,height=1,radius=1):
            self.height = height
            self.radius = radius
        
    def volume(self):
        return self.pi * self.radius**2 * self.height
    
    def surface_area(self):
        pass

Comment: Please don't put multi-line Python code excerpts into comments, as they lose indentation and are generally unreadable. BTW, the initial version of your code has `self.pi` indented too far: it should be indented the same as the `def` lines. However, as Eugene mentions you can't actually use `self.pi` there. And that's a really pathetic approximation for pi. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `self` from the second line. `self` is used only inside class methods to access class instance. But class attributes declared on class-level apply not to single class instance, but to class itself and all its instances: so they do not require `self`.